# How to enable communication between a device on guest network to a device on parent (main) network?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, subnet

I have 2 wifi routers, 1 is an old TP-WR740N that I am using as a switch to give wired access to my devices. And another new Archer A6. My main network is on A6 and the WR740N is added as an AP. I want my laptop(192.168.1.100) to be accessed by my android phone which is connected to the A6. I tried to enable "Allow Guests to Access My Local Network" to make it work, but it didn't do anything. Is there a way to make this communication work?

Comment: Except for that option, your question does not explain how a guest network even comes into play. It doesn’t sound like you want a guest network. Do you have one? // Please describe the network setup in greater detail. Which cable goes to which device (and which port on that device), what IP subnets are in play, …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every wireless router has Ethernet ports.

```
Hook up old router LAN port to your network. 
(Use the router GUI setup page to do this)
Give old router a static IP on your network. 
Turn DHCP OFF on the old router.
```

Your wireless routers may have a setting for "Wireless Isolation" . Turn that setting OFF.

You may also wish to upgrade the firmware in your routers. If they are working, that may not be the issue, but do not overlook it.

You probably now want to reset both routers.

If you have continued issues, do a hard (factory) reset on both routers (nominally both at 192.168.1.1) and start again.

Now use whatever Ethernet ports you want.

This setup works very reliably for me.

Ultimately you may wish to try a different router since the above has worked for a couple of decades with different makes and models of routers

Comment: I have done the part where I am supposed to hook the second router to the first one. The problem is accessing them. I am not sure how to turn off that isolation mode you spoke of. And this isolation mode, is it located on the parent router or the child router?

Comment: Look in the Router GUI setup on both routers and find the Wireless Isolation setting. Review the Router Documentation or Help. Turn that OFF if the setting exists.  Make sure there is only one DHCP server (main router). The setup outlined works (using it here on my own routers) so check carefully for wireless isolation.

Comment: I checked it and it seems to be turned off. There seems to be some other issue with it.

Comment: I suggested updating firmware. Review the main steps (LAN to LAN (Ethernet), static IP, DCHP OFF on second router and this setup works.  Also do not overlook a soft reset.  Finally, you can do a hard reset and set up again.

Comment: I did all that, turning off DHCP was the first thing I did. I noticed my secondary router has DHCP disabled but for some reason under the DHCP clients my devices are showing up. Don't know if it is some UI shit, or it is actually assigning private addresses to them itself.

Comment: Also, should the clients that are connected to the secondary router, be shown in the primary one?

Comment: If you set up as suggested, all clients will be on one subnet and will show up that way on either router.

Comment: I did, but I am not getting the results as expected.

Comment: You probably should hard reset your routers and start again - something is wrong that regular settings are not able to correct.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention, both my routers have the same Mac addresses. It was because my IP authenticates using mac addresses so I had to use that and then I didn't bother to change the old one's to something else.

Comment: Change MAC addresses so they do NOT conflict. New information.

Comment: apologies if it was important, I just noticed it when I was looking the DHCP server for the main router.

Comment: Yes important.  Hard reset probably would have fixed this.  Please do set up properly and it should work fine

Comment: Well, i did that and released the previously assigned address and now I am unable to connect to the secondary router at all.

Comment: Try a different router.  The router connections as suggested have worked for me since XP with about a half dozen or more different routers and makes

Comment: Weird. I might have to buy a new router I guess. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I think so - Thanks.